# Why does my tableview return the same Parse image for every cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have my tableview returning titles, their descriptions and now I am trying to return images. It currently returns only one image for all of my cells. Is this because I'm storing it in a UIImage?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import ParseUI

class YourEvents: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var currentuser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username


    //array
    var testArray = [String]()

    var testdecr = [String]()
    var image = UIImage()

   //  var imagestored = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Companies")
         let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["username"] as? String

        query.whereKey("createdby", equalTo:"\(pUserName)")
        // let runkey = query.orderByAscending("companyname")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                //do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                    for object in objects {

                        let load = object.objectForKey("companyname") as! String
                        self.testArray .append(load)

                        print(self.testArray)

                        let load2 = object.objectForKey("companydescription") as! String
                        self.testdecr.append(load2)

                        print(self.testdecr)

                         if let userImageFile = object["imagefile"] as? PFFile {
                         userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                if let imageData = imageData {
                                     self.image = UIImage(data:imageData)!
                                    print("done!")
                                    self.do_table_refresh()

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }


                        }

                }
             } else {
                //log details of failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error?.userInfo) ")

            }


        }

        // reload  UIViewController and UITabkeView
        sleep(3)

        do_table_refresh()
    }

    func do_table_refresh () {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),  {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return testArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourstartups", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourStartupsCell
        cell.lbTitle!.text = self.testArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbDescription!.text = self.testdecr[indexPath.row]
        cell.logo!.image = self.image


        return cell
    }

}
```

[image: Table View]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making an array of PFImage objects, and then in your table view delegate method you can simply access the element at the current row in your index path. Right now your method to get the data is being called once and therefore setting your image to the last fetched object, but since the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` is being called each time a cell is loaded, you need to keep the images in an array, as you are doing with the text labels.

Comment: When I try to set var image = [UIImage]() and then append it like  self.image.append(UIImage(data:imageData)!) . I get a breakpoint http://postimg.org/image/6rgw9acut/ . The reason I don't set it as a PFObject is because that gives an error also.

Comment: Try using an `NSMutableArray` and append PFImages to it @NiallKehoe . That way you won't have to worry about indexes not existing. See here: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/loading-remote-images-stored-on-parse/ and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555713/how-can-i-use-a-pfimageview-in-swift

Comment: Doesn't matter now, Parse just announced they are shutting down :( so start migrating to something else...http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Yeah, saw it today. Any idea where you might go to?

Comment: Maybe check out the new AWS mobile hub, or possibly Firebase, although that is less featured. Parse has open sourced their server so I might try to host that on Heroku or Google App Engine to avoid disruption with my current apps. What about you?

Comment: I don't really know. I think Couchbase is definitely an option.